# Return a list where items in list 1 and list 2 match

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

Let's assume I have 2 `List<T>` List1 and List2 that look like this:

**List 1**:

```
[ID:1, Name:"item1"]
[ID:2, Name:"item2"]
[ID:3, Name:"item3"]
[ID:4, Name:"item4"]
```

**List 2:**

```
[ID:2, Name:"item2"]
[ID:3, Name:"item3"]
[ID:5, Name:"item5"]
[ID:6, Name:"item6"]
```

How can I get a list that contains only the objects that are in both lists? Using the example above, I want to return:

```
[ID:2, Name:"item2"]
[ID:3, Name:"item3"]
```

Modifying the original lists is OK. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is there a "retain all" or intersection function available? I'm not familiar with C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  var result = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

Is the most succinct. However keep in mind it is using the default equality comparer which may or may not work for you. If not, you can provide your own:

```
    public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
    {
        public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
        {
            return x.Id == y.Id;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
        {
            return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

  var result = list1.Intersect(list2, new MyEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: @Broken: There's no "definitely" here - it's only if the type doesn't override Equals appropriately *and* if there are actual different objects in the lists (as opposed to equal lists). It's good to point out the *possibility* of needing a custom equality comparer, but it's not *definitely* a requirement.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - yes, although the sample provided by OP looks like a list with a custom class to me, so in that case it wouldn't work w/o custom comparer.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: How do you know that the custom class doesn't override Equals and GetHashCode appropriately?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I have a hunch ;-) But yes, that's certainly a possibility, and a cleaner (imo) approach too.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Also bear in mind that anonymous types automatically implement Equals and GetHashCode in a generally-sensible manner. I wish I could get the compiler to provide that implementation automatically for custom types :)

Answer (score 4):

If there are no duplicates in the list you can do this:

```
var combinedList = list2.Intersect(list1).ToList();
```

**Edit:**

As @Matt Greer pointed out you will need a custom equality comparer for this to work as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Like jQuery, the answer is always LINQ!

```
var intersection = list1.Where(item => list2.Contains(item)).ToList();
```

Assuming the list contains a copy of the actual reference. If not, then do:

```
var intersection = list1.Where(item => list2.Count(match => item.ID == match.ID && item.Name == match.Name) > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't use Count like this - use Any if you absolutely have to. However, Contains will use Equals anyway, so if that's been overridden, it'll do the right thing. Intersect would still be better though.

Comment: I was curious, so I read up on Any. Is that just because it will return if any match, VS enumerating the entire list?

Comment: Yes - it's more efficient *and* it expresses what you're interested in more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

Using lua code here:

```
ArrayList1={}
ArrayList2={}

function inTable(tbl,val)
   for _,v in ipairs(tbl) do
      if v==val then return true end
   end
   return false
end

function getSame(tbl1,tbl2)
   returnArray={}
   for _,v in ipairs(tbl1) do
      if inTable(tbl2,v) then table.insert(returnArray,v) end
   end
end

newArray=getSame(arrayList1,arrayList2)
```

I'm not too familiar with C#.

Comment: It's concept that a person should learn.  Copying and pasting something isn't helpful to anybody.  It's the closest thing to pseudo code I have at the moment.  I don't know C# well enough to give a c# example.  I provided what I could.  I want to help with the issue, I'll help in any way I can.

Comment: Actually, in this case using the C# equivalent of this code would be a bad option, as LINQ is a much better approach. Note that this approach is also O(N * M) - it could get very expensive with two large tables.

Comment: Yes, after seeing the other examples, you are right.  I knew it would be expensive.  I was providing a concept.  I'm sure it could be provided in another situation :)  For all intents and purposes, however, this could be probably be applied to another situation.  Thanks for the comments ;)