# Multiple keyword search using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have been stuck on this for a day and have made very little headway.

I have products that I want to be able to filter by keywords along with other static variables. These keywords anyone can type in the search bar. Where I am getting stuck is when someone enters multiple keywords. If there is only one keyword the query works great.

How can I search for multiple keywords that all relate to an item and only return the items that match the keywords?

Example keywords: Tent, Blue, Hiking

```
public static List<ProductObjectModel> GetProductsByKeyword(string keywords)
{
    using (TraegerEntities db = new TraegerEntities())
    {
        List<ProductObjectModel> lstObj = new List<ProductObjectModel>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords))
        {
            string[] keyword = keywords.Split(',');

            var lstAnon = (
                from r in db.Products
                join i in db.ProductImages on r.ProductId equals i.ProductId
                join c in db.ProductCategories on r.ProductId equals c.ProductId
                join cl in db.ProductCategoryList on c.ProductCategoryListId equals cl.ProductCategoryListId
                join k in db.ProductKeywords on r.ProductId equals k.ProductId
                join kl in db.ProductKeywordList on k.ProductKeywordListId equals kl.ProductKeywordListId
                where r.Archive == false
                where i.SmallImage == true
                where keyword.Any(kw => kl.Keyword.Contains(kw))
                group new
                {
                    Products = r,
                    ProductCategoryList = cl,
                    ProductImages = i,
                    ProductKeywordList = kl
                } by r.ProductId
            ).ToList();
        }

        foreach (var item in lstAnon.Skip(beginRange).Take(endRange))
        {
            ProductObjectModel obj = new ProductObjectModel();

            obj.ProductDetails = item.First().Products;
            obj.CategoryList = item.First().ProductCategoryList;
            obj.Images = item.First().ProductImages;
            obj.KeywordList = item.First().ProductKeywordList;

            lstObj.Add(obj);
        }

        return lstObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you apply `.Contains()` or I believe that is simply for linq-to-sql.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: JohnSaunders I've heard you say that over and over and over, you should write a user script that auto inserts this comment :).

Comment: @JonH, He probably has one, there is a plugin out there that lets you specify your own "auto" comment so its just two clicks to post it :)

Comment: @JonH, In .Any() `where keyword.Any(kw => kl.Keyword.Contains(kw))` I am using `.Contains`. Is it because my keywords are in an array that it's only finding the first keyword?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,

when user inserts `"Tent, Blue, Hiking"`, you want to display all the items that have these three keywords?

If that's the case, simple swap from `.Any()` to `.All` should help you.

Like so: `where keyword.All(kw => kl.Keyword.IndexOf(kw, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)`

and trim your stuff:

```
var keyword = keywords.Split(',').Select(y => y.Trim());
```

Comment: That's correct, if someone enters those three keywords I want to find all products that match those three. I've split the string to create an array of keywords. I changed `.Any()` to `.All()` and am now returning 0 results for one to many keywords.

Comment: It could be the case of character casing(eg lowercase), and it can also be because of spaces. See the updated post.

Comment: I tried a few variations of that.
`var keyword = keywords.Split(',').Select(y => y.Trim());` had an empty string at the end of the array. So I change my array to,
`string[] keyword = keywords.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` I also messed around with the `where` clause. Still returning 0 results. Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: It's a little bit too hard to say what's the problem at this point. I assume you tried removeemptyentries + sleect with trim()?

Answer (score 0):

After a week of working on this problem I finally found the solution. By comparing two lists I'm able to get the result I need. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5584430/2147603) was my solution.

```
public static List<ProductObjectModel> GetProductsByKeyword(string keywords)
{
    using (TraegerEntities db = new TraegerEntities())
    {
        List<ProductObjectModel> lstObj = new List<ProductObjectModel>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords))
        {
            string[] keyword = keywords.Split(',');

            List<ProductObjectModel> lstAnon  = (
                from r in db.Products
                join i in db.ProductImages on r.ProductId equals i.ProductId
                join c in db.ProductCategories on r.ProductId equals c.ProductId
                join cl in db.ProductCategoryList on c.ProductCategoryListId equals cl.ProductCategoryListId
                join k in db.ProductKeywords on r.ProductId equals k.ProductId
                join kl in db.ProductKeywordList on k.ProductKeywordListId equals kl.ProductKeywordListId
                where r.Archive == false
                where i.SmallImage == true
                select new ProductObjectModel
                {
                    Products = r,
                    CategoryList = cl,
                    KeywordList = kl,
                    Images = i
                }
            ).ToList();

            var lstFiltered = lstAnon;

            List<string> keywordList = new List<string>(keywords.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

            foreach (string word in keywordList)
            {
                var tempList = lstAnon.Where(r => r.KeywordList.Keyword == word).ToList();
                lstFiltered = lstFiltered.Intersect(tempList, new MyEqualityComparer()).ToList();
            }

            foreach (var item in lstAnon.Skip(beginRange).Take(endRange))
            {
                ProductObjectModel obj = new ProductObjectModel();

                obj.Products = item.Products;
                obj.CategoryList = item.ProductCategoryList;
                obj.Images = item.ProductImages;
                obj.KeywordList = item.ProductKeywordList;

                lstObj.Add(obj);
            }
        }

        return lstObj;
    }
}

public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProductObjectModel>
{
    public bool Equals(ProductObjectModel x, ProductObjectModel y)
    {
        return x.ProductObjectModel.ProductId == y.ProductObjectModel.ProductId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ProductObjectModelobj)
    {
        return obj.Products.ProductId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is to query **everything** and then filter in-memory? That's not a great solution. What if your product table has 9 billion rows?

Comment: Fortunately enough for us we wont have 9 billion rows. But you make a point. I'd love a better solution.